# How to show the monthwise result using SQL query for the following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I'm having a database table named `user_transaction` whose structure is as below:

```
transaction_id    mediumint(6)   UNSIGNED (PK)
transaction_no    varchar(55)
transaction_cc_avenue_no    varchar(55)
transaction_card_category    varchar(100)
transaction_user_id      varchar(32)
transaction_user_name    varchar(255)
transaction_user_email_id    varchar(255)
transaction_deal_code    varchar(10)
transaction_dc_id    smallint(4)
transaction_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_discount    float(10,2)
transaction_total_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_data_assign    enum('0', '1')
transaction_status    enum('success', 'inprocess', 'fail', 'cancelled')     
transaction_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_user_id    varchar(32)
```

I'm using UNIX Timestamp values to store the dates in the column `transaction_date`. Now I want to display the monthwise no. of transactions of different transaction_status(i.e.Total transactions took place on each date,total no. of transactions of status 'success', 'inprocess', 'fail' and 'cancelled') for all the transaction_dates present in a table. Those records should be grouped by month. I tried a lot to get this result but not getting any success. For your reference I'm giving below my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `total count`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`, SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled` FROM user_transaction GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eric Wich & @D Mac: I want to show the month no. well. How should I write the query then?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show year and month (you'll need year so the months are disambiguated across year changes).

Comment: @Eric Wich: By using your query I'm getting datewise results not monthwise.

Comment: Did you change transaction_date to be a date instead of a bigint? And did you include the statement "GROUP BY MONTH(transaction_date)"?

Comment: @DMac:No, I didn't change the transaction_date datatype to date from bigint but used GROUP BY MONTH(transaction_date)

Comment: That's why it isn't working. MONTH(transaction_date) does not work if transaction_date is not a date or datetime type column. MONTH needs a date or datetime input.

Comment: By running this query I'm getting the results but the mdates are displayed instead of month number. How to show only month and year?   SELECT COUNT(*) `total count`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`, SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled` FROM user_transaction GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)

Answer (score 1):

It will be a lot easier if you just set transaction_date as a date. Then you can use the built-in functions.

For example, you could do

```
SELECT year(transaction_date), month(transaction_date),
    sum(whatever), ...
FROM user_transaction
GROUP BY YEAR(transaction_date), MONTH(transaction_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(transaction_date), MONTH(transaction_date);
```

If you have an aversion to changing the data type of transaction_date, then you can convert it on the fly with FROM_UNIXTIME. I don't recommend that, because it is an extra (unnecessary) layer of processing in every query. Nonetheless, that would mean you can leave your schema the way it is and write:

```
SELECT year(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)), month(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)),
    sum(whatever), ...
FROM user_transaction
GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date))
ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date));
```

Nasty, isn't it? You're better doing a 'ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN transaction_date transaction_date date' and then you get all the advantages of doing date math with the easy to use MySQL functions.